# Kafka Streams WindowStore Fetch Record Ordering

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The Kafka Streams 2.2.0 documentation for the `WindowStore` and `ReadOnlyWindowStore` method `fetch(K key, Instant from, Instant to)` states:

> For each key, the iterator guarantees ordering of windows, starting
>   from the oldest/earliest available window to the newest/latest window.

None of the other fetch methods state this (except the deprecated `fetch(K key, long from, long to)`), but do they offer the same guarantee?

Additionally, is there any guarantee on ordering of records within a given window? Or is that up to the underlying hashing collection (I assume) implementation and handling of possible hash collisions?

I should also note that we built the `WindowStore` with `retainDuplicates()` set to `true`. So a single key would have multiple entries within a window. Unless we're using it wrong; which I guess would be a different question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other methods don't have ordering guarantees, because the order depends on the byte-order of the serialized keys. It's hard to reason about this ordering for Kafka Streams, because the serializers are provided by the user.

> I should also note that we built the WindowStore with retainDuplicates() set to true. So a single key would have multiple entries within a window. Unless we're using it wrong; which I guess would be a different question...

You are using it wrong :) -- you can store different keys for the same window by default. If you enable `retainDuplicates()` you can store the *same* key multiple times for the same window.

Comment: Yes, storing multiple entries for the same key within a window is what we want. In our case, we have status coming in multiple times per second with the same key, and I want to window that data on a per minute basis. In a perfect world, entries with the same key in a window would be ordered by the given timestamp, but it appears the store preserves insert order.

Comment: Yes. The store preserves insert order. Instead of using `retainDuplicates()` you could maybe switch to a `key -> list-of-values` pattern for each window -- this allows you to overwrite an existing window with a new window (and insert the record into the list based on timestamps)